# Restore the state my project was in 11/10/2021 into another temporary project, so I can only get the order of work items from Boards from that day

Tags: azure-devops, backup, azure-boards

I want to restore the state my project was in 11/10/2021 into another temporary project (not the one I am currently using), so I can only grasp the order of work items from Backlogs from Boards for that day. I did not delete the project. I just changed the Area Paths for Teams and the order of work items changed. I just want to have a reference in a separate temporary project, so I can compare work items order between them and restore correct one to the actual backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like this is going to be quite tricky, I think that the closest you will come to doing this will be to create a new project and then try to use the open-source migration tools at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration. We used an earlier version of this for an Azure DevOps carveout from another tenant, and it worked well, but we didn't have your "restore-to-point-in-time" use case.

I think that what you're going to need to do is use the `ReplayRevisions` on the `WorkItemMigration` class, and then you're probably going to need to write some custom WIQL to get only what you're looking for. It's even conceivable you might need to extend this to get the functionality you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Will try it with our IT. It seems like it's not resolving my issue (but it may help in another ;)

Comment: Ultimately, I think that the code in that project may wind up being more of a guide for you to figure out how to play forward history (if it even is capable of doing that).